# Build a custom maven lifecycle without creating a plugin

Tags: maven, lifecycle

I need to create a custom maven lifecycle and I would like to do it on the same pom.xml of my application. Is it possible?
Here is the relevant code that I have and the results that I got:

<project_root>/src/main/resources/META-INF/plexus/components.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<component-set>
  <components>
    <component>
      <role>org.apache.maven.lifecycle.Lifecycle</role>
      <role-hint>Configurator</role-hint>
      <implementation>org.apache.maven.lifecycle.Lifecycle</implementation>
      <configuration>
        <id>Configurator</id>
        <phases>
          <phase>process-resources</phase>
          <phase>login</phase>
        </phases>
        <default-phases>
          <process-resources>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:resources</process-resources>
        </default-phases>
      </configuration>
    </component>
  </components>
</component-set>
```

<project_root>/src/main/resources/META-INF/maven/lifecycle.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<lifecycles>
  <lifecycle>
    <id>Configurator</id>
    <phases>
      <phase>
        <id>process-resources</id>
      </phase>
      <phase>
        <id>configure</id>
      </phase>
    </phases>
  </lifecycle>
</lifecycles>
```

<project_root>/pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
    http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.luismmribeiro.config</groupId>
  <artifactId>Configurator</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
    </resources>
  </build>
</project>
```

result:

>mvn configure

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ---------------< org.luismmribeiro.config:Configurator >----------------
[INFO] Building Configurator 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.154 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-03-12T19:24:38Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "configure". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException
```

Comment: Which problem are you trying to solve by creating your own lifecycle? Frankly, I guess your approach is overly complicated.

Comment: I would ask the same: Why do you need that? What is the purpose?

Comment: I'm using maven to replace some placeholders in some files (depending on the environments) and, after that, to execute 2 sh files. Infact, I selected this approach exactly to be simple: just define the lifecycle with 3 phases (1 goal per phase) and execute the last phase. What I wouldn't like to do is to be forced to create a plugin. That's why I would like just to define and execute this lifecycle in one pom.xml.
And my question is exactly that: is this possible?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your replacement and shell commands should happen during the normal build, I would add them to appropriate phases of the standard build cycle.

If they form a separate action, I would write a Maven plugin.

I have never seen a solution of your problem using custom lifecycles and cannot say whether this is possible.

Comment: What I'm trying to do has nothing to do with Java compilation lifecycle. It is something else. That is why I want to create a new lifecycle. I can create it using a plugin, but I would like to have something simple and, if possible, selfcontained in the pom.xml file.

Comment: You can use the antrun plugin and implement your behaviour in ant. This would be contained in the POM itself.

Comment: or you can have three POMs: one for the plugin, the project, and the root pom. The root pom has the other two as modules so that the plugin can be built and used in a single session

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest migrating to gradle. It offers almost all base functionalities of maven and allows for the creation of custom tasks written in groovy all in the same configuration file.

Comment: Gradle and Maven are not comparable. Gradle is a groovy version of Ant.

Maven provides and solid set of patterns that encourage developers to build code in a consistent way. It means a developer that knows Maven can pickup any project with maven and just use it.

In my experience no two Gradle projects are alike in the same way ant projects aren't. From a commercial perspective using Maven makes a lot more sense in terms of succession planning for software developer that any of the alternatives.